# Keep background out of content

Tags: html, css

I'd like to exclude the background or background image from the rest of the content like in this
[jsfiddle.net/vyqqsy1f/17/](http://jsfiddle.net/vyqqsy1f/17/)

```
<div id="container">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* Standard syntax */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
  /*background-clip: content-box;*/
}

#container
{
    /*width:70%;*/
    width:670px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Any way to do that ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vyqqsy1f/18/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the background of your text to be clear. All you have to do is to wrap the text in a div:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
body
{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#A0A0A0, #FFFFFF); /* Standard syntax */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
  /*background-clip: content-box;*/
}

#container
{
    /*width:70%;*/
    width:670px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#inner {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: auto;
}
```